# How do I generate a list of permutations based on given characters and a length?

Tags: python, algorithm, permutation

For example,

I have a list of characters that I want to generate permutations of e.g. ['*', '+'] and a length that I want the permutations to be generated off e.g. 2. In other words, I want to find all the combinations of the supplied list up to the supplied length. A call to generatePermutations might look like this.

```
generatePermutations(['*', '+'], 2)
```

Which should return:

```
*, *
*, +
+, *
+, +
```

Another example would be:

```
generatePermutations(['*', '+'], 3)
*, *, *
*, *, +
*, +, +
*, +, *
+, *, +
+, *, *
+, +, *
+, +, +
```

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: How have you gone about doing that? What happened?

Comment: Look at `product()` from `itertools`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `itertool.product`. What you are asking for is the [cartesian product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product).

Examples

```
>>> list(itertools.product(['*', '+'], repeat=2))
[('*', '*'), ('*', '+'), ('+', '*'), ('+', '+')]
>>> list(itertools.product(['*', '+'], repeat=3))
[('*', '*', '*'), ('*', '*', '+'), ('*', '+', '*'), ('*', '+', '+'), ('+', '*', '*'), ('+', '*', '+'), ('+', '+', '*'), ('+', '+', '+')]
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. For some reason it didn't jump out to me on the API. Thanks!